# JQuery/Javascript pageflip

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

can somebody tell me how this pageflip is implemented, and any samples would be appreciated.
http://www.cataloguecentral.com.au/Catalogue/BIG-Christmas-Gift-book-6610

Thanks

Comment: They are using 2 (left & width) animations. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

How about [this sprite animation technique](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/07/20/javascript-sprite-animation-using-jquery/), very small amount of code needed. Another animation is [here](http://clickheredammit.com/pageflip/) and looks just like what you want!

Comment: thanks the one in sitepoint seems to be good :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears they use the following jQuery plugin

> [jCaousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: i voted up by mistake, but i wasnt asking about the carousel :)

Comment: You can always remove a vote by clicking on the up arrow a second time. I'll live.